# Using std::async breaks my program somwhere else, access violation reading

Tags: c++, pointers, asynchronous, mfc

I'm working on an MFC application, written in visual C++ in visual studio 2015. I'm calling a function of an object using a pointer to it. I get the exception "Access Violation reading location 0x4a522c31" here:

```
void Handler::NotifyEvent(I_Handler::eNotification nNotification){
  for (t_InterfaceList::const_iterator iter = m_oClientList.begin(); iter != m_oClientList.end(); iter++){
          (*iter)->I_Handler_OnEvent(nNotification);
   }
}
```

The class Handler is this:

```
class Handler{
  typedef list<I_Handler*> t_InterfaceList;
  t_InterfaceList m_oClientList;
  static Handler* GetInstance();
  bool AddClient(I_Handler * pInterface);
  bool RemoveClient(I_Handler * pInterface);
  void OnTimer();
  void NotifyEvent(I_Handler::eNotification nNotification);
}
```

The class I_Handler is this:

```
class I_Handler {
  public:
    virtual void I_Handler_OnEvent(eNotification nNotification) = 0;
};
```

The software works like this:

- The class Handler has a list of clients, who are of class I_Handler.
- When something happens inside OnTimer(), the clients must be notified.
- To notify them, inside OnTimer(), NotifyEvent() gets called.
- NotifyEvent() iterates over the list of clients and calls each function I_Handler_OnEvent()

I have a class somewhere else that controls a window (it's a CFormView) and it's also a client of Handler, meaning that this class is something like this:

```
class View_Control : public CFormView, public I_Handler{
  DECLARE_DYNCREATE(View_Control)
  protected:
    View_Control();          
    virtual ~View_Control();
  public:
    void I_Handler_OnEvent(eNotification nNotification) override;
}
```

I have checked and the pointer address is correct, it points to the object of class View_Control who registered as client.

AddClient gets called inside a function of ControlView, like this:
`Handler::GetInstance()->AddClient(this)`. I checked `this` and `*iter`, they always have different values, but are close (in one execution, `*iter` was `0x00595E78` and `this` was `0x00595DA8`. However, the exception always happens reading the same address, which is nowhere near these pointers.

The full error message is as follows:
`Exception thrown at 0x6ce42dc6 (ucrtbase.dll) in program.exe: 0xc000005: Access violation reading location 0x4a522c31.`

`std::async` is used to launch tasks in parallel in different functions inside the class `Handler`. Inside the function `OnTimer()` I check for the task to be ready with a `wait_for` on the future object returned by `std::async`. When I get `std::future_status::ready`, I call `NotifyEvent()` and everything crashes. Note that if I comment out the `std::async` call, then the task is not run and `NotifyEvent()` works as intended.

It looks as though the fact that a function executes in other thread created by `std::async` breaks the ability of `NotifyEvent()` to call a member function by a pointer to the object.

Why does this happen?

Comment: The primary suspect is that your object has been destroyed.

Comment: The windows still exists, so I guess the object must exist too. How do I check this? I don't destroy de object until the user clicks on the "Close" button, so it should be there

Comment: Use debugger. Make sure the object is initialized properly and not destroyed when you use it.

Comment: @freejuices But does the `Handler` exist?

Comment: Are you applying any casts to your View_Control * before passing it to AddClient?

Comment: @AviBerger no, inside a function of View_Control it calls Handler::GetInstance()->AddClient(this);

Comment: @molbdnilo If the function NotifyEvent() is being called, doesn't that mean that it exists? Given that it's a member function of the class Handler

Comment: A common problem with this pattern occurs when one of the event handlers modifies the list of clients, thus invalidating the iterators.  You're using a `std::list`, so iterator invalidation is rare, but it's still possible.  For example, if a handler removes itself from the list, then `iter` will become invalid and it will be impossible to advance it to the next client in the list.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy I've had that happen, but I think it's not the problem here. I only have one client and its event handler doesn't change the list. Also, the crash occurs the very first time the handler gets called, so it breaks in the first client, before any handler had chance to run.

Comment: @freejuices It's possible to call a function of a non-existent object, for instance through a pointer or reference. I would check whether `0x4a522c31` is near `this` or `*iter`. If it's neither, check `(*iter)->I_Handler_OnEvent` (look in `*iter`'s vtable).

Comment: @molbdnilo I think you're on the right track. `iter` is `0x00595E78` and `this` is `0x00595DA8`. They're close, but not equal because View_Control is also CFormView I believe. However, I'm afraid I don't know how to check `*iter` vtable. What should I look for and where?

Comment: The difference in pointer values is due to multiple inheritance and is expected. My previous comment about casting was to check if you were doing something clever and wrong that might get you the wrong pointer value, but you are handling that correctly. Regarding the comment by @AdrianMcCarthy, if more than 1 thread is involved or I_Handler_OnEvent() might (indirectly) call RemoveClient(), that needs a serious look. Otherwise, we might just be looking in the wrong place and need to take a step back.

Comment: @AviBerger, @molbdnilo So it looks as though this has to do with the threads involved. I'm starting a std::async task on a function of `Handler`, and calling wait_for() on the OnTimer function. When the status is `ready`, I call NotifyEvent() and this causes a crash. However, if I do away with the std::async stuff and call NotifyEvent from OnTimer it just works.